# How to work with conditional operator in JSF 1.2 value expressions?

Tags: jsf, el, conditional-operator

I have this output component and now I want to control the text, which should be visible in my gui:

```
 <h:outputText value="#{Bean.descriptiontext ne txt.priority ? Bean.descriptiontext : ': -' }" />
```

But this expression doesn´t work. "txt.priority" is a text module in my external resource bundle. Where is the mistake in this JSF expression?

I get a ParseException ! "Encountered "}"

Comment: Define 'doesn't work'.

Comment: have you tried !=. BOth ne and != will do the same thing

Comment: Please copypaste the entire exception.